# Реализация Toggle посредством addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

друзья! Помогите реализовать функцию Toggle посредством addEventListener. Суть, у меня есть две кнопки, одна с цветами, другая с картинками, мне нужно что бы когда нажимаешь на кнопку с картинками - кнопка с цветами исчезала, т.е, должна происходить замена  div, а у меня они просто валяться вниз.

```js
let colorText = document.querySelector('#colors');
let imgText = document.querySelector('#image');
let parentBlock = document.querySelector('#parentColor');


colorText.addEventListener('click', colorCreate);
imgText.addEventListener('click', imgCreate);


function colorCreate (event) {
  let block;
    for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
      block = document.createElement('div');
      block.className = 'block'+i + ' allBlock';
      parentBlock.appendChild(block);
      } 
}


function imgCreate (event) {
  let img;
  for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    img = document.createElement('div');
    img.className = 'img'+i + ' allImg';
    parentBlock.appendChild(img);
    } 
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;;
}

body {
  background: yellow;
}

.parentColor {
  height: 300px;
  width: 302px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 152px);
  top: calc(50% - 152px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  }

.allBlock{
  border: 2px black solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.allImg{
  border: 2px black solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}


.block1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.block2 {
  background-color: green;
}
.block3 {
  background-color: orange;
}
.block4 {
  background-color: tomato;
}
.block5 {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}
.block6 {
  background-color: pink;
}
.block7 {
  background-color: violet;
}
.block8 {
  background-color: black;
}
.block9 {
  background-color: brown;
}


.img1 {
  background-image: url(https://сезоны-года.рф/sites/default/files/images/shkolnikam/gora.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img2 {
  background-image: url(http://wallpapers-image.ru/oboi/wallpapers/wallpapers-mountains-01.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img3 {
  background-image: url(https://www.biletik.aero/upload/iblock/cc9/cc9928c77eb9f350b08ae12ab0d6b431.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img4 {
  background-image: url(http://worldclassmag.com/files/nodus_items/0004/2216/_cache/fit988x988-image-2216-1553268843.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img5 {
  background-image: url(http://topcitaty.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-770x450.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img6 {
  background-image: url(http://rosa-tv.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/gory.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img7 {
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSNwDb-N27y_SExymRdR0Kj2infncF-yZyZSWpXquuZIUYCG2kr&s);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img8 {
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR3oDxLwRxAJD2X17S3JKPXQxR2RZpSIPsTFJ_upVhruD2KGsDT&s);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img9 {
  background-image: url(http://migranov.ru/nepal/everest/thamserku.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 
  <p id="colors">Colors</p>
  <p id="image">Image</p>
  <div id="parentColor" class="parentColor"></div>
  <div id="parentImage" class="parentImage"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Прошу извинение, если плохо, объяснил. И буду рад любой помощи, Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let colorText = document.querySelector('#colors');
let imgText = document.querySelector('#image');
let parentBlock = document.querySelector('#parent');

colorText.addEventListener('click', colorCreate);
imgText.addEventListener('click', imgCreate);

function colorCreate(event) {
  parentBlock.innerHTML = '';
  let block;
  for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    block = document.createElement('div');
    block.className = 'block' + i + ' allBlock';
    parentBlock.appendChild(block);
  }
}

function imgCreate(event) {
  parentBlock.innerHTML = '';
  let img;
  for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    img = document.createElement('div');
    img.className = 'img' + i + ' allImg';
    parentBlock.appendChild(img);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  ;
}

body {
  background: yellow;
}

.parent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 302px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 152px);
  top: calc(50% - 152px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.allBlock {
  border: 2px black solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.allImg {
  border: 2px black solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.block1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.block2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.block3 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.block4 {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.block5 {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

.block6 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.block7 {
  background-color: violet;
}

.block8 {
  background-color: black;
}

.block9 {
  background-color: brown;
}

.img1 {
  background-image: url(https://сезоны-года.рф/sites/default/files/images/shkolnikam/gora.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img2 {
  background-image: url(http://wallpapers-image.ru/oboi/wallpapers/wallpapers-mountains-01.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img3 {
  background-image: url(https://www.biletik.aero/upload/iblock/cc9/cc9928c77eb9f350b08ae12ab0d6b431.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img4 {
  background-image: url(http://worldclassmag.com/files/nodus_items/0004/2216/_cache/fit988x988-image-2216-1553268843.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img5 {
  background-image: url(http://topcitaty.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-770x450.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img6 {
  background-image: url(http://rosa-tv.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/gory.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img7 {
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSNwDb-N27y_SExymRdR0Kj2infncF-yZyZSWpXquuZIUYCG2kr&s);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img8 {
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR3oDxLwRxAJD2X17S3JKPXQxR2RZpSIPsTFJ_upVhruD2KGsDT&s);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img9 {
  background-image: url(http://migranov.ru/nepal/everest/thamserku.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<p id="colors">Colors</p>
<p id="image">Image</p>
<div id="parent" class="parent"></div>
```

Comment: Боже, как же просто... Спасибо Вам огромное, хорошего вечера!!

Comment: @SumskyiVasyl Пожалуйста. Успехов!